# How to change the position of those buttons?

Tags: html, css, button, center

I found this script for menu, but i don`t know how to put the buttons on center.
There are the html and css file: http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/1589746
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can remove

```
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

and add

```
#cssmenu > ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: it works. One more thing, that bar that it`s on background, how can i make it repeat for the hole witdh of the page?

Comment: @is.insane It depends, I should see full page. You could try negative margins to expand it; or `position: absolute` with `left:0` and right:`0`, assuming all its ancestors have `position:static`

Comment: @is.insane Please don't link malicious websites. My antivirus found a JS:Redirector-BJC[Trj] in your page

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn`t know...nvm, i changed the position from fixed to relative and it work. Thanks for help :)